# Pause function to wait for ajax request inside of a websocket

Tags: javascript, ajax, async-await

I have a WebSocket that adds people to a messaged list when they receive a message. I use a fetch to get information from the server to build the messaged list, but I cannot find an easy way to get the code to pause until the fetch completes. I cannot add await because the funciton is inside a websocket that isn't async. Does anyone have any suggestions on this?

```
        socket.on('receive_message', function(data) {
            let messaged_user_li = document.getElementById('messaged_user_li'+data['from_user']);
            console.log('messaged_user_li: '+messaged_user_li)
            if (messaged_user_li == null) {
                console.log('if fired')
                //THIS is the fetch I want to pause the function until complete. Note that the await here does not work since the funciton isn't async.
                await fetch('/get_messaged_user/'+from_user).then((response) => {
                    response.json().then((data2) => {
                        loadMessagedUser(data2[0].id, data2[0].avatar, data2[0].username, data2[0].last_seen);
                    });
                });
                messaged_user_li = document.getElementById('messaged_user_li'+data['from_user']);
            }
            console.log('messaged_user_li: '+messaged_user_li)
            let message_user = document.getElementById('message_user'+data['from_user']);

            let message_target = document.getElementById("message_target"+data['from_user']);
            if (messaged_user_li.classList.contains('active') == false) {
                messaged_user_li.classList.add('flash-message');
            }
            if (message_user != null) {
                data = `
                <li class="clearfix">
                    <div class="message-data text-right">
                        <span class="message-data-time">just now</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="message other-message float-right">`+data['message']+`</div>
                </li>`;
                message_target.innerHTML += data;
                //Move scroller to bottom when message received
                myDiv = message_user.querySelector(".chat-history");
                myDiv.scrollTop = myDiv.scrollHeight;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually You can add async function in socket.on

`socket.on('receive_message',async function(data) {`

Comment: Thanks! I added that, but for some reason my messaged_user_li shows up as null even with the await forcing it to wait for the fetch to complete. Got any ideas why?

Comment: `console.log('messaged_user_li'+data['from_user'])`and check if it is expected string. `null` is because there  is no element with that id

Comment: I checked that and it is null. The function I am trying to pause is what populates the dom element that is needed for this query. I believe the await is working and giving it time to populate, but for some reason the query does not return what is needed.

Comment: can you show `loadMessagedUser `

Comment: I fixed this issue by chaining the response.json() to the statements prior which causes the await command to work as well as adding the async to the top of the socketio function delcaration.